# Redirect azure stream to put request

Tags: node.js, azure-blob-storage, nodejs-stream

I am trying to upload file from azure to external service -

```
            var requestStream = request.put(requestParams, function (err, res, body){

                if(err){
                    deffered.reject(err);
                    return;
                }

                deffered.resolve([res, body]);
            });

            storage.getBlobToStream('recordings', fileName, requestStream, function(err, blobResult, blobResponse){

                if(err){
                    return deffered.reject(err);
                }
            });
```

I got an error from external service that content is empty. My previous code looks like this and it works -

```
     storage.getBlobToLocalFile( ...)
     fs.createReadStream(..).pipe(request.put(requestParams, callback))
```

I am feeling I have missed something due my little experience with nodejs.  I have used [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#streaming) and [azure-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-storage) libraries. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `getBlobToStream`, try using [`createReadStream`](http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/BlobService.html#createReadStream__anchor) to read a stream from Azure blob storage.

***Example:***

```
storage.createReadStream(containerName, blobName).pipe(request.put(requestParams, cb));
```